# Counting occurences of substring ignoring case in JAVA

Tags: java, substring

I am trying to count the occurences of div tag in my html file. When I search for `div`, I get 2 and for `DIV`, I get 1650. So ideally when i use `sHtml.toUpperCase()`, and then search for `DIV`, I should get **1652**. But I am getting **1656**. What might be going wrong here?

```
        /********* Counting occurences of div **************/
        String findString = "DIV";
        int lastIndex = 0;
        int count = 0;

        while (lastIndex != -1) {

            lastIndex = sHtml.indexOf(findString, lastIndex);

            if (lastIndex != -1) {
                count++;
                lastIndex += findString.length();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Count of div = " + count);
```

Comment: The specific test case that is giving the odd numbers would let someone tell exactly what is going on. It is most likely one of the general answers below.

Comment: This won't really work, because your method will also pick up comments like `<!-- DIV for main -->` and similar.  You should really use an HTML parser, it's the only way.

Comment: oh yeah. Makes sense. Thanks. Also I am a newbie in this, what sort of HTML parser can I use in eclipse?

Comment: @tanvi That's off-topic for SO, but I believe [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) is a popular parser.

Comment: @tanvi [Google says there's lots.](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+html+parser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are picking up substrings that were mixed-case before - say, `Div`. This is not a good reason to count `"div"`s, though, because you would pick up parts of longer words (say, `Division` or `Divorce`).

If you want a better count, you could use a simple regex to do the counting:

```
"[</]div[ />]"
```

This regular expression will match a `div` that is preceded by `<` or `/`, and followed by a space, `/`, or `>`:

```
Pattern countRx = Pattern.compile("[</]div[ />]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = countRx.matcher(sHtml);
int count = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks - I added the flag to make the match case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

By the process of elimination, you must have some combination of `Div`, `DIv`, `DiV` or `dIV` as well. It is also possible that your text contains a word with *div* in it (like *long division*).